# Consuming an RSS feed from a parent site collection errors Forbidden

Tags: rss

I was hoping this was going to be easier... I have a top level site collection with site collections underneath. I would like to publish one list from the parent site to the daughter sites. I was thinking along the lines of using an RSS viewer, but when I specify the full URL to the RSS feed the daughter site errors

ProtocolError occured trying to complete the request. The server returned a status code of : Forbidden and the status description is : "Forbidden"

This is running on my development SP2010 farm, all local to my workstation, no proxies in IE or web.config.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in an authenticated environment, the RSS viewer Web Part won't work.

Try using the xml Web Part instead, or a client side script that will read the RSS via AJAX.

Comment: Not entirely true, if you're in an authenticated environment running Kerberos, then the RSS viewer web part will work.

Comment: @PirateEric thanks, I didn't know it was dependent on the authentication method.

Comment: Kerberos eliminates the double hop effect in that case and allows for the authenticated feed to be consumed by the RSS web part.